# Is there any shorter syntax for changing several directory levels back up with bash cd?

Tags: bash, cd

If I need to change to some directory several levels up, I usually do this in bash:

```
cd ../../../../some/other/folder
```

Since it is quite annoying to type all those periods and slashes, I was wondering if there is some shorter way to type it; like for example:

```
cd ..4/some/other/folder
```

I have not been able to find it so far from for example `cd --help`.

Comment: I am not sure, but [pushd and popd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands) could be useful

Comment: That's a good point and that is sometimes useful, but it requires that I "have been there before" and remembered to `pushd` to get to where am now.

Comment: The special variable `$CDPATH` might also be of interest.

Comment: unless your directories are *very* deeply nested, I can't see this as a real practical issue

Comment: @choroba that is good to know as well, but it mostly looks useful if that folder I am switching back to is usually the same one.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I guess I am just lazy; I often get annoyed with this going just 3 or 2 levels up...

Comment: When you really lazy, you could also make a function that looks for a subdir `some/other/folder` relative to the (parent of the ..) parent of your current path.

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard way.

You can declare a function that takes a number of parent directories as the first argument, and the relative path as the second one:

```
cdu () {
    local n=$1
    local p=""
    while ((n--)) ; do
        p+=../
    done
    cd "$p/$2"
}
```

You can then shorten `cd ../../../bin` to `cdu 3 bin`

What I use is

```
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
```

To get 6 levels up, I just type `...` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> three times.

Comment: With `cdu` Op can write `cd ../../../../some/other/folder` as `cdu 4 some/other/folder`

Answer (score 1):

according to cd man page, the immediate answer is "no".

if it helps, you may add the following to your .bashrc:

```
export prev1=".."
export prev2="../.."
export prev3="../../.."
export prev4="../../../.."
```

and so on.

example:

```
export prev4="../../../.."
mkdir -p /1/2/3/4/5
cd /1/2/3/4/5
pwd => result is /1/2/3/4/5
cd $prev4
pwd => result is /1
```